# Functions.php error - when trying to change the theme

Tags: themes, functions, errors

After trying to replace the wordpress theme , it says that the functions.php file in the theme catalogue - the last line - is not ok

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in ... /themes/themename/functions.php on   line 1500

line 1500 is actually only symbol       ?>

**EDIT**

ok, here is the pastebin link of the functions.php file that has error

http://pastebin.com/by5TtZq6

p.s. i am wondering - since its supposed to be a ready made template - then how could it be error - its supposed to work

p.s. may be its some kind of thing that can be messed up by changing wordpress settings or it uses some bad plugins ? ( like permalinks or some cache plugin etc. ) ...

Comment: remove the last `?>`

Comment: @One Trick Pony that's a perfectly valid answer; why put it as a comment? :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that means there's an extra close-function tag somewhere in your functions.php file, `$end;`, `}` or such. You'll have to pick through the code to find it. A text editor that color-codes code can help with this, but you'll still have to click around and find it.

Best of luck!

Comment: it says the same - for other themes also , there is only       ?> sign    on that line ,  should there be also $end; somewhere on the last line

Comment: More likely it's an extra $end or } somewhere earlier in your code - it won't be on that line that's showing the error. If you want to post the entire functions.php file here (or over on pastebin.com and share a link) someone might be able to help you pick through and find it.